# A weighted "stars and bars" variation

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So the "stars and bars" problem is to find the number of multisets of $k$ choices of values from $n$ distinct values.  What happens if we weigh each choice according to how many distinct values are in a possible choice?  For example, if we assign the weight $w^c$ for a choice of $c$ distinct values, how can we calculate the (weighted) sum over all choices?

To make this clear, suppose one particular configuration, or choice, is

$$\star| \star \star | \star || \star \star \star$$

Here there are $k=7$ choices of values, and there are $n=5$ distinct possible values.  For this particular configuration, there are $c=4$ distinct values chosen.  This would give this a weight of $w^c = w^4$ for this combination.

Comment: Just to confirm, the configuration can be described as the tuple $(1, 2, 1, 0, 3)$, which contains $4$ distinct possible values, and thus will receive $w^4$? I would imagine you can do this with generating functions.

Comment: @GarethMa: Yes, that's correct.  I'm simply trying to multiply each combination by the weight.  If you can show me how to do this I would accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total weight would be given by:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dbinom{n}{i}\dbinom{k-1}{i-1}w^i$$

For your example, your case where $k=7,n=5$, you have:

$$\dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{6}{0}w + \dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{6}{1}w^2 + \dbinom{5}{3}\dbinom{6}{2}w^3 + \dbinom{5}{4}\dbinom{6}{3}w^4 + \dbinom{5}{5}\dbinom{6}{4}w^5$$

Essentially, choose $i$ distinct values to be chosen (so you know you will have a weight of $w^i$ for each of these). Now, how many ways are there to assign values? Well, there are $k-i$ stars left to distribute and $i-1$ bars. So, there are $\dbinom{k-i+i-1}{i-1} = \dbinom{k-1}{i-1}$ ways to assign the values.

Comment: I thought they were asking for a closed form haha, I wonder if there is though?

Comment: @GarethMa according to WolframAlpha, a closed form is $$nw\cdot {{_2}F_1}(1-k,1-n;2;w)$$ but that doesn't look much easier